# how can i make for google extension background page which using my website

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome-extension, extension-methods

I need Chrome Extension which Open Newtab page and Newtabpage Will be My Website Link and this website will be only background Page because i dont want my webpage link will be in adres bar. can you help me ? or suggest my how can i make it

Comment: Its is very unclear what your specific programming issue is here? Please refer to the question asking guidelines.

Comment: i need chrome extension which make this punction s  using javascript or html

Comment: This isn't a `how-to` site. Do your own research then when you have specific code problems come back and you will get plenty of help

Comment: yes i have ok thank you i post my code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**You can use background pages:** https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.

But if you want a new tab, the link will appear anyway. Using background pages, you can put custom html, as iframes and your website will load. But the user won't see.

If you want that your user see the page, use popups, tabs or custom javascript injection 
instead.

Comment: update url give me error can yo tall me what can i do Manifest should not have field update_url.
Invalid version number in manifest: 2.0. Please make sure the newly uploaded package has a larger version in file manifest.json than the published package: 2.0.